# Drag drop title window over Canvas?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

i am trying to catch the dargOver and dragDropped event on canvas.. for titlewindow. but moving title window over the canvas does not fire these two events ? is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch those events on Canvas
See here http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_7.html

Canvas inherits EventDispatcher.